# How to change the background color of button in windows phone application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, button, windows-phone-7, background-color

I am developing window phone 7 application in C# & silverlight 4. I am new to the silverlight.I have two buttons in my application for different purposes. I want to change the color of the button dynamically when the button gets clicked. So I am using the following code

```
 IncomeButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

But it is not working. Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the styling of a button from it's own click event comes with a catch. Peter elaborates here.

[Why can't I change the Background of my Button on a Click event? - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-can-t-i-change-the-background-of-my-button-on-a-click-event.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply execute `IncomeButton.UpdateLayout()` after changing button's color.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into that "simple" problem. Instead of using Peter's "button styling change" thing, I simply placed a rectangle below the button and changed it's color with the Rectangle.Fill property in the Click event of the button. Works fine for me.