# How to highlight the clicked button on the user interface in window phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, button, windows-phone-7, highlighting

I am developing window phone 7 application in C#. I am new to the silverlight. I have more than one buttons in my application for different purposes. I am performing the click operation on one of the button amongst these buttons. Now I want to show the selected button to the user on the user interface screen. So I want to highlight that selected button so that the user interface will show that particular clicked button in a different manner than the other button on the screen. Previously I have tried for the following scenario

[How to change the background color of button in windows phone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562022/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-button-in-windows-phone-application)

Can you please tell how should I highlight the clicked button ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Comment: Is there a reason the answer in the question you linked doesn't work for you? Perhaps this question is different somehow?

Comment: its working. But how should I maintain the state of clicked button so that I can show it visually in my application ? or How can I change the color of the selected button ? What code should I write ? Please help.

Comment: In my scenario I want to click on only one button from the available two button. It is either or situation for button controls. Can you please help me

Comment: Your question is not clear enough... Maybe if you put a small XAML example of what you need to do would help.

Comment: @Shailesh Jaiswal: Did I understand your question correctly? Or did you just want this effect when one of the Buttons has Focus?

Comment: Yes you understand my question. I wanted this effect when any button gets clicked it should change the background color of that clicked button.

Comment: I have used user <Style> property in app.xaml and I am using the following code on the clicked button

Comment: Button ButtonObj = sender as Button;

            Style ButtonStyle = Application.Current.Resources["ButtonColorStyle"] as Style;
            ButtonObj.Style = ButtonStyle;
            ButtonObj.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

Comment: Its not working very fine as I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for the RadioButton functionality on a couple of Buttons. In that case, you can just re-template a RadioButton with the default Button-Template and add the VisualState for Checked. This example will make the Background turn Red for the latest Clicked Button, I hope that's what you're after

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"
                 GroupName="buttonGroup"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Content="Some Button"/>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"
                 GroupName="buttonGroup"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Content="Some Button 2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the RadioButtonStyle1

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```